# Repair with data loss did not fix index corruption. What now?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, corruption

A few months ago we migrated our SQL Server 2014 database to a virtual environment.

Soon afterwards, corruption started showing up in indexes, causing all sorts of trouble.

I've made repairs using `DBCC CHECKDB (repair_allow_data_loss)` a few times, and while it improves the situation, it never fully gets rid of the corruption within certain indexes.

Some CHECKDB results:

```
Msg 8977, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 452196661, index ID 1, partition ID 72063073671905280, alloc unit ID 72063073860190208 (type In-row data). Parent node for page (3:266287) was not encountered.
Msg 8980, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 452196661, index ID 1, partition ID 72063073671905280, alloc unit ID 72063073860190208 (type In-row data). Index node page (1:68133), slot 60 refers to child page (3:299616) and previous child (3:264884), but they were not encountered.
Msg 8936, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 452196661, index ID 1, partition ID 72063073671905280, alloc unit ID 72063073860190208 (type In-row data). B-tree chain linkage mismatch. (1:62351)->next = (3:429015), but (3:429015)->Prev = (1:285490).
Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 452196661, index ID 1, partition ID 72063073671905280, alloc unit ID 72063073860190208 (type In-row data). Page (3:468549) is missing a reference from previous page (3:261242). Possible chain linkage problem.
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get my database back to a perfectly clean state? There is no clean backup from which to restore since this has been going on for a while.

I am going to attempt a new VM to see if that will fix the problem. I haven't been able to identify any I/O subsystem flaws.

Comment: If you have no IO problems and you have allowed data loss and the DB still wont report good, recommend scripting out the db and migrating the data. Hopefully that isnt your problem :)

Comment: @MarkThomas `Msg 8936` is indeed a hardware problem. You have to run hardware diagnostics to find possible problems. By repairing with `repair_allow_data_loss` --> you have [**tried the last resource first**](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/corruption-last-resorts-that-people-try-first/)